# Is there a list of ALL potential mates/traps under 10 moves or so?

Tags: checkmate, opening-traps

Wiki has a couple of pages on opening traps, but I get the sense there must be more, and these are just representative samples:

[List of chess traps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_traps)
[Checkmates in the opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmates_in_the_opening)

PS. The "10 move" limit is really just for practical reasons - I know that the opening can be longer, but I am just looking to make sure I don't fall for any famous trap early on in the game....

Comment: I think I have seen a book like "Common Opening Traps". Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: There are far too many to list.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest investigating [Bill Wall's Chess Page](http://billwall.phpwebhosting.com/), specifically:

1. [700 Opening Traps](https://issuu.com/visualdesigngraphics/docs/700traps)
2. Miniatures that relate to your favourite openings, e.g. [500 Caro-Kann Miniatures](http://billwall.phpwebhosting.com/collections/500_Caro_Minis.txt)
3. The PGN files related to you favourite opening

Comment: http://www.chesstree.net/ has a nice opening explorer online version with the Bill Wall and Wikipedia traps built in.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a list of ALL potential mates/traps under 10 moves or so?

"No" is the obvious answer if you do the maths regarding just how many there could potentially (to use your word) be. Starting with all 32 pieces on the board the possible number of positions in the first 10 moves is mind-boggling.